# How do I retrieve images from JSON into React?

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I want to use JSON to retrieve my images along with their file location. My program looks like the code below.

I've tried with `{photos.Lillian.portfolioImage}` and with `JSON.stringify(photos.Annalise.portofolio` however, none of them can display the images. I've done a `console.log();` and checked if the data can be read and it does appear however, the images will not appear. I've checked the source address and it works when I add it here `<img src="./img/TheGuardian/Lillian.png">`.

What is my error? Do I need to reformat the object called from JSON? I've seen one can use parse and fetch however, this is used for APIs and as far as I can see, this isn't?

Here's my JSON:

```
{
  "Lillian" : {
    "type": "The Guardian",
    "portfolioImage": "./img/TheGuardian/Lillian.png"
  },
  "Annalise" : {
    "type": "TheGuardian",
    "portfolioImage": "./img/TheGuardian/Annalise.png"
  },
  "Raven" : {
    "type": "DCComics",
    "portfolioImage": "./img/TheGuardian/Raven.png"
  }
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import photos from './images.json';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(photos.Annalise.portfolioImage));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>beeccy´s portfolio.</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          This was a test to present images from my portfolio.
        </p>
        <img src={photos.Lillian.portfolioImage} alt="Lillian" />
        <img src={photos.Raven.portfolioImage} alt="Raven" />
        <img src="JSON.stringify(photos.Annalise.portfolioImage)" alt="Annalise" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What about creating an <img> tag and placing the route into the src attribute?

Answer (score 5):

Like in HTML, you want to set the `src` attribute of an `img` element the source to the image. The following example also shows how you can loop over the JSON and show all images at once.

```js
const JSON = {
  Lillian: {
    type: 'The Guardian',
    portfolioImage: './img/TheGuardian/Lillian.png'
  },
  Annalise: {
    type: 'TheGuardian',
    portfolioImage: './img/TheGuardian/Annalise.png'
  },
  Raven: { type: 'DCComics', portfolioImage: './img/TheGuardian/Raven.png' }
};

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(JSON).map(key => (
          <div>
            {JSON[key].type}
            <img src={JSON[key].portfolioImage} key={key} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This works. How can you print the type, assuming that's a string?

Comment: Simply wrap it in curly braces like `{JSON[key].type}`. Updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = 

    { 
           "Lillian" : { "type": "The Guardian", "portfolioImage":         "./img/TheGuardian/Lillian.png" }, 

           "Annalise" : { "type": "TheGuardian", "portfolioImage": "./img/TheGuardian/Annalise.png" }, 

           "Raven" : { "type": "DCComics", "portfolioImage": "./img/TheGuardian/Raven.png" } 
    };

    let images = [];

    for(let item in obj){
       images.push(item.portfolioImage);
    }
```

By doing this you can retrieve images from the object of objects into the images array

Answer (score 0):

In data u should use require()

```
const JSON = {   
   Lillian: {
    type: 'The Guardian',
    portfolioImage: require('./img/TheGuardian/Lillian.png')   
   },   
   Annalise: {
    type: 'TheGuardian',
    portfolioImage: require('./img/TheGuardian/Annalise.png')   
   },   
   Raven: { 
    type: 'DCComics', 
    portfolioImage: require('./img/TheGuardian/Raven.png') 
   } 
};
```