# How to give relative local path from json in React.js?

Tags: json, reactjs

How do i use a local path from Json to my React components rendering,

an `<img  src={this.props.imgUrl}/>`. I searched for answer all over the internet, but NO luck :(

```
NOT WORKING :(
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "imgUrl": "./Pictures/219.jpg"
    }
]

WORKING, BUT TURTLE SPEED :/
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "imgUrl": "http://www.placekitten.com/200/200"
    }
]
```

import React from 'react'
class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={this.props.imgUrl} />
            <p>Name: {this.props.name}</p>
            <p>Id: {this.props.id}</p>
            <p>Price: {this.props.price}</p>
        </div >
    )
}
```

}

Comment: it's probably referencing the wrong directory. if images are showing up correctly with a URL, your rendering is fine. you haven't told us anything about your server or setup so it's going to be impossible to debug

Comment: Could you provide file hierarchy of your project, especially for Pictures and current component?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Pictures is the folder storing many jpg files and it sits at the root Component. What component are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
"imgUrl": "file:/Pictures/219.jpg"
instead of
"imgUrl": "./Pictures/219.jpg"

Also make sure, you give the absolute path.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. No luck, the picture does not show up.

Comment: Thank you for reply. it still not working. picture not show up. Do I have to config  in webpack.config file?

Comment: Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854494/how-do-i-retrieve-images-from-json-into-react. It should help.

Answer (score -1):

How I usualy do it is that I do not include imageurl if the pictures are local , rather doing it by searching public/assets by asset name. 
I have prepared little [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-water-yw2ju) for you.